# Basic vector question.

Tags: vectors

The opposite edges of a tetrahedron are $a,a'; b,b'; c,c'$. If $a\cdot a'=b\cdot b'=0$, then show $c.c'=0$ and $a^2 + a'^2 = b^2 + b'^2 = c^2 + c'^2$.

[image]

Comment: Your equations do not match you picture.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, we have $c=b-a$, $c'=b'+a$, and $b'+a-b=a'$. Then
$$c\cdot c'=(b-a)(a+b')=a\cdot b-a\cdot a+b\cdot b'-a\cdot b'=a\cdot (b-a-b')=a\cdot(-a')=0$$
For the other statement, observe that $a-b-a'+b'=0$, so $a-a'=b-b'$ and similarly with $c+a+c'+a'=0$. Now, using the conditions $a\cdot a'=0=b\cdot b'$ we can expand
$$ a^2+(a')^2=(a-a')^2 =(b-b')^2=b^2+(b')^2\,.$$